# modify location permit request with MAUI

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, maui

I need to modify the message that appears when requesting location permissions from the user in MAUI for both Android and IOS, I also need to modify the type of location, I need it to always be accurate, I couldn't find how to do it, I'm working with .NET 6
Can you give me an example code please?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?tabs=macios)?  For iOS you need to provide a value `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.  [Accuracy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geolocation?tabs=macios#accuracy) is also covered in the docs.

Comment: Yes I read it and I knew about IOS but I need Android too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309764/customising-the-default-device-access-permission-dialog-in-android

Comment: This is the system's behavior and there is no api can change it. In addition, the third party app can't get the permission to do this.