# Popup that comes when app ask for location access

Tags: flutter, android-permissions

My app's location permission popup is like this:

[image: My app's location permission popup is like this]

I need it like this (found on net):

[image: I need it like this (found on net)]

I'm doing my project in flutter, so what modifications I need to do get popup like in second image.

So I'm expecting to get solution to my issue solved

New : can shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() be used for above question?
if yes how to use?

Comment: Android and iOS permissions don't look the same this is the expected behavior and cannot be changed

Answer (score 2):

The popup shown in the first screenshot (which is from yours) is the Android location permission popup. See [this section](https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions#upgrade-to-precise) from the Android Developers page.

The popup shown in the second screenshot is the iOS location permission popup. See [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102515) on the "Give apps permission to use your location" section.

You can't get the second popup on Android.

Comment: thanks you for letting me know the difference

Answer (score 0):

You can not add custom message in android location permission popup, but you can add in iOS you can also see the screenshot you added with custom message is on iOS.
For iOS you can add these line in `iOS/Runner/info.plist`, and you can change the message:

```js
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location in the background.</string>    
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string
```

And for android what you can do is add a custom dialogue to show you message and then after that you can open the default popup.

Comment: can you please give any reference regarding custom dialogue.

Comment: You can use this code for foe custom dialogue and then after it show default popup.

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible to do. have a look at the following article which explains the reason behind this perfectly.

[check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309764/customising-the-default-device-access-permission-dialog-in-android)

Comment: The link is broken